# What is the meaning of the inflection 若かりき?

Tags: i-adjectives, archaic-language

I encountered what I think is an inflection of the adjective 若い and I couldn't find a suitable explanation for it.

Here is the inflection in context:

はにかみて君若かりきさかづきを挙げて銀座に相別れにき…

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This entry weblio entry seems to provide some information [若かりし](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8B%A5%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A%E3%81%97)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

若かりき is an archaic form of 若かった.

[き](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8D/#jn-50189) is an auxiliary verb indicating past tense. So 君若かりき is in the sentence-ending form and means *you were young*. As explained in the Weblio entry, し is a pre-noun form of き. Thus 若かりし is usually followed by a noun, like 若かりしとき = when (subj) was young.

Comment: Thank you. In keeping with this discussion, would you agree that the にき at the end of the sentence is the 連用形　に　of the auxiliary verb ぬ indicating completion followed by the auxiliary verb き marking the past tense? (thus meaning something similar to てしまった)

Comment: @grove Yes that should be correct. https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8D